# Are Christian scholars of the Old Testament aware of classic medieval Jewish commentaries on the Bible?

Tags: exegesis, bible

I ask this because I sometimes come across blog posts by supposedly learned Christian pastors discussing some passage in the Old Testament that is unclear in some way, and the pastor comes up with various theories of how to explain it, while failing to mention the often quite straightforward and logical answer to the same question given by even the most basic Jewish medieval commentators, such as Rashi or Ramban, seemingly because they are unaware of them.

Is it simply the case that these sources are not taught in Bible colleges? If not, why not?

Comment: Most pastors are not working academics or scholars. But if they're using more than pop-level Christian commentaries, then Jewish sources are almost certainly referenced from time to time. And from my experience at Bible college, while Rashi may not have ever been explicitly prescribed (and neither were most Christian commentators; each subject would typically only have one required commentary), the library did have lots of non-Christian resources, including the full JPS Tanakh Commentary series.

Comment: An example would be helpful, firstly to demonstrate that this is factual and secondly to demonstrate its working.

Comment: [Ramban's straightforward logic](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/960660#v10).

Comment: @lucian, your link is neither a) biblical commentary, nor b) the Ramban. It is the Rambam (with an "m"), who is a completely different author, and the subject matter is Jewish Law as derived from the Talmud, not commentary on any text, definitely not a Biblical text. The Rambam never produced any biblical commentary, as far as I am aware

Comment: @JoelFan: It references and interprets scripture in a traditional fashion.

Comment: @lucian let me clarify what I mean by a Biblical commentary... Such a work will start each essay with a direct quote (or citation) of a particular Biblical verse, partial verse, or passage of verses. It will then provide one or more interpretations or explanations of the particular verses it addresses. The Rambam (with an "m", which you linked above) is NOT a Biblical commentary. I don't know any clearer way of explaining that. Examples of Biblical commentaries include, as I originally mentioned, Rashi and Ramban (with an "n")

Comment: Perhaps it will help to provide the Latin renditions of these names... Rashi = Salomon Isaacides... Ramban = Nachmanides. Either version of their names will yield search results if you're unfamiliar